# Cannot append label to div

Tags: jquery

I created this div via code>

```
 var text = $('<div class="form-group">').append('<label class="control-label">')
        .text("test string")
        .css("font-weight", "bold")
        .append('<span>').css('color', '#253a27').text('32');

 $('#result').append(text);
```

unfortunately I can't see any text in the div `result`

Expected output:

```
<div class="form-group>  
    <label class="control-label">test string <span style='color:#253a27;'>32</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want the HTML of the DIV to look like?

Comment: `.text()` replaces the entire contents of the DIV with that text. The first `.text("test string")` replaces everything, including the `<label>`. The last `.text('32')` then overwrites everything again, including the `<span>`.

Comment: @Barmar I want something like: "test string 32" where 32 is colored

Comment: Show the desired HTML in the question.

Comment: Because of method chaining, everything in your code is operating on `<div class="form-group">`. You're not concatenating things.

Comment: That expected output is not HTML. Please show something like `<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">...`. So we can see how you want everything to be nested.

Comment: @Barmar Ok updated

Comment: The wya you are doing the chaining is wrong.

Comment: @sfarzoso not sure how you accepted an answer that does not produce the output you wanted. Span is not in the label.

Comment: @epascarello the output is the same

Comment: @sfarzoso um Above has label with a span in it `<div><label><span></span></label></div>`. The selected one is `<div><label></label><span></span></div>` That does not look the same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do dot use the `text()` method twice. The second use replaces the content of the div with "32". Try this if it suits you:

```js
var text = $('<div class="form-group">').append('<label class="control-label">test string</label>')
  .css("font-weight", "bold")
  .append('<span style="color: #c00;"> 32</span>').css('color', '#253a27');

$('#result').append(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: seems like the text is all colored?

Comment: @sfarzoso It is colored  in red.

Comment: @razvan the span is outside the label. OP wants the span to be inside the label element.

Comment: Not sure how this is the answer since it does not even result in the code OP said they wanted.... ANd has zero explaination why it does not work

Answer (score 1):

The chaining does not apply the css and text to the element you just appended, it is only adding it to the first element. When you use append, the reference does not shift to the element you just created, it stays with the element you are currently on. That is why everything you set is being applied to the div.

You need to set the properties to the elements themselves. Easiest thing is to break it up into its own parts.

```js
var span = $('<span>')
  .css('color', '#253a27')
  .text('32');
var label = $('<label class="control-label">')
  .text("test string")
  .css("font-weight", "bold")
  .append(span)
var text = $('<div class="form-group">')
  .append(label)
$('#result').append(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="result"></div>
```

If you were to do it with chaining, you would have had to use find()

```js
var text = $('<div class="form-group">')

text
  .append('<label class="control-label">')
  .find('label')
    .text("test string")
    .css("font-weight", "bold")
    .append('<span>')
    .find("span")
      .css('color', '#253a27').text('32');

 $('#result').append(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .text() at all:

```
var text = $('<div class="form-group">').append('<label class="control-label">test string <span style="color:#253a27">32</span></label>')
  .css("font-weight", "bold")

$('#result').append(text);
```